# Trouble with pandas merge function

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two panda's data frame using the `merge` function. Here are the top few lines of the both the data frames.

```
newDF
    0   1x
0   1   FARM PRODUCTS
1   11  FIELD CROPS
2   112 COTTON, RAW
3   1129    RAW COTTON, NEC
4   1131    BARLEY
```

and

```
df_2012
    0   1          2           3    4   
0   1   657042  52539820    103009  10818958    
1   11  613499  51051986    99650   10525341    
2   112 10710   233790         0    0    
3   1121    0   0              0    0          
4   1131 13276  998109       3560   0
```

when I merge with the following command:

```
pd.merge(newDF, df_2012, on = [newDF.columns[0]], how = 'right')
```

I am getting the following:

```
    0   1x  1   2   3            4
0   1   NaN 657042  52539820    103009  
1   11  NaN 613499  51051986    99650   
2   112 NaN 10710   233790  0   0   
3   1121    NaN 0   0   0   0   0   
4   1131    NaN 13276   998109  3560
```

I don't understand why the new merged data frame's `'1x'` column has all `NaN`s. I thought those keys which doesn't appear on the left data frame, that is in `newDF`, those will appear as `NaN`s. For the rows whose keys matches in both data frames will show the other column values from both the data frames.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for any input to make me understand this problem.

Comment: I've got expected result... Which `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: I see. I will update it and rerun the code. Thanks @Anton Protopopov